# Function parameter type depending on type of other parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to write a function which has the following type signature:

- parameter `a` is either of type `string` or `undefined`
- parameter `b` is a `string` if `a` is also a `string`, otherwise it is a `number`

My approach up to now was the following:

```
function myFunction<X extends string | undefined>(
    a: X,
    b: X extends undefined ? number : string,
) {
    // ... do stuff ...
}
```

Calling `myFunction` works just as expected, ie. `myFunction('a', 'b')` works while `myFunction(undefined, 'b')` throws an error. However, when I try to use the parameters in the function body, I don't have any typing support:

```
function myFunction<...>(...) {
    if (a !== undefined) {
        // a is a string -> b must also be a string
        b.split(''); // -> Property 'split' does not exist on type 'X'
    }
}
```

Do I have to cast inside my function or can I somehow convince typescript to infer my type?

EDIT: Complete example: https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4DFzXmAPADUQFMAPKIsAEwGdFqoAnGMAc0QB9FxKjhmjKAPgAUAKEQTEAQwBcifABpxkgEZzCpclVrde-SogD8iMCGQqiDRHPpNWSgJSIA3sokxgiYVMQBCALz+XFR6YAJOrpJRiAD0MdKIMLQ+tsxsALSCiCooIPTSADbUcNlECamsbtEqAHTUAA4FMFDCAOStDgDcVQC+oj1AA

Comment: Could you add playground with this example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript does not support narrowing parameters one based on another. As far as the compiler is concerned `a` and `b` are independent and checking `a` will not impact the type of `b` even if the conditional type ties them together conceptually.

Answer (score 0):

Overloading the function is the way to go here. Also, remember that all your TypeScript types will be lost during transpiling to JavaScript. So conditional typing isn't really possible, since this would be a runtime check. You have to write those checks yourself.

It would also be better to bring the parameter a to the second position and make it optional, then you can write a clean check:

```
function myFunction(b: string | number, a?: string) {
    if(typeof a !== "undefined") {
        b = b as string;

        b.split("");
    }
}
```

Comment: Point is to force TS to detect that b is string based on argument definition

Comment: Well, the `b = b as string` was exactly what I wanted to avoid; but apparently that doesn't work...

Comment: As Titian pointed out in his answer, the compiler doesn't know about types that are dependend on the type of other variables.

Comment: You could also write `function myFunction(b: string & number, a?: string)`. Then you can get rid of the `b = b as string`