# Typescript: function with n parameters of union type T, why does inferring one param's type not infer all, when callers must match types?

Tags: typescript, generics, type-narrowing

Given this function signature: `function foo<T extends X | Y>(bar: T, baz: T) {}`
Callers cannot mix `X` and `Y`. The compiler enforces that `bar` and `baz` are either **both `X`, or both `Y`**

However, a type check on `bar` narrows its type, but not that of `baz`. Proof: [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBOBbADgQwE4FMA8AKorgB5S5gAmAzojVNjGAOaIA+iYIqARrtgB8ACkwAuRIQA0iXhMIBKCdz4DEAbwCwAKESIYwRMKgBPdLjiHMiALx3EAIhX9sDhRp169eKCGxJrAGpZAG5PRABfEgAbGlwPXS8fPyQABjDEiJ0s7R0UDBxcYQBGGQAmBQz8rDxhAHJMOpk63jrKvLQaotLEFraqzsL6xvLKoA)

Can this symmetry outside the method body be continued into the method body somehow, so that 1 type check narrows all parameters?

Comment: I know `ts-essentials` has an `assert` method that can do this, but I'd like a native solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong; a legal call to compare would be

```
compare<string | number>(10, "");
```

Thus it is not valid to narrow one parameter based on the other's type

Comment: Ah, true, thanks. But do you know a way to specify a generic param in the way my question intended then? To have n params of T, where T is multiple types but the actual types of all params can only be exactly 1 of the given types?

Comment: Ah, actually, my question then becomes this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54650571/function-parameter-type-depending-on-type-of-other-parameter